# Optimizing simple PixiJS stage

Tags: performance, canvas, webgl, pixi.js

I'm totally new to Pixi, WebGL, Canvas... and actually I'm not making a game but a React webapp

What I want to build:

- Draw an image (A4 document scan, generally jpeg/png from 100k to 1m)
- On top of each word of the image, draw an interactive rectangle which can be hovered/clicked
- Thanks to deep learning/OCR, I already have the size of the image and the relative positions of the document words
- Documents can have from 0 to 3000 words
- Ability to zoom

[image]

I tried first with regular CSS, but clearly found out that using position absolute was not performant to position thousands of rectangles on the document: performance was not good on scroll for example.

I tried using PixiJS to draw the rectangles on top of the image. The result is better, but I still see some performance problems on my old computer, particularly when the image is zoomed (it affects scroll so it's not really related to JS code I guess)

---

Here is the result: https://dhatim-poc-mlhafeauav.now.sh/

The solution I used for the above document of:

- An html img tag
- A transparent canvas sitting on top of the image, on which I draw the rectangles (Graphics, drawRect)

---

Can someone tell me how to optimize this for older computers?
How can I audit the performance of this solution properly?
Is there an easy way to simulate an old computer on my dev env? particularly regarding GPU instead of CPU throttling?

---

I tried to follow some recommendations found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas

- I use a background image instead of drawing the image to the canvas (not sure it has a large impact because there is no "game loop")
- I use Math.floor for the position of the words (the PixiJS roundPixels option)
- I also tried with a small canvas and a scale transform: https://build-ybbdwoumva.now.sh/

---

Are there other recommendations you could give to have better performances?

Particularly:

- should I use Sprite or Graphics for the rectangles?
- should I use canvas or WebGL?
- how can I measure my performance optimizations? I currently feel I'm totally blind and not even sure that what I do produce a better result without concrete numbers

Thanks

Comment: What if you put all your rectancle elements in a parent element and set the `style.transform` scale on that element. Then you only have to update a single eleement to zoom.

Comment: Yes actually I could do that and handle the zoom with only a scale operation without requiring any redraw on the canvas. Actually I will probably do that but currently I already encounter some slowness just by scrolling on an older computer, without even redrawing on the canvas. I guess it has something to do with the image size and the poor graphical card on the computer and wonder if I can do something about it. Also, the zooming or browser resizes are not the most common operations so if it takes 300ms it's not a big deal for my usecase

Answer (score 1):

What if you put all your rectancle elements in a parent element and set the style.transform scale on that element. Then you only have to update a single eleement to zoom.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".areas>div");
const pair = document.querySelector(".viewer>div");

const imgWidth = 600;
const imgHeight = 849;
const numAreas = 1000;
for (let i = 0; i < numAreas; ++i) {
  const x = rand(imgWidth - 10);
  const y = rand(imgHeight - 10);
  const w = rand(5, imgWidth - x);
  const h = rand(5, imgHeight - y);
  
  const area = document.createElement("div");
  area.className = "area";
  area.style.left = px(x);
  area.style.top = px(y);
  area.style.width = px(w);
  area.style.height = px(h);
  parent.appendChild(area);
}

document.querySelector("#zoom").addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const s = e.target.value / 100;
  const transform = `scale(${s},${s})`;
  pair.style.transform = transform;
});

function rand(min, max) {
  if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0;
}

function px(v) {
  return `${v}px`;
}
```

```css
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
.viewer {
  position: relative;  /* so children are relative to this */
}
.area { 
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.area:hover {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.areas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  /* to match image */
  width: 600px;
  height 849px;
}
.areas>div {
  position: relative;  /* so children are relative to this */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.areas>div>div {
  position: absolute;
}
.ui {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  color: white;
  padding: .5em;
  z-index: 3;
}
.ui>input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewer">
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg">
    <div class="areas">
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui">
 <label for="zoom">zoom</label>
 <input type="range" min="1" max="500" value="100" id="zoom">
</div>
```

I didn't bother to clean it up or set scrollbars etc but it seems to work

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but I already tried to render 1000 elements with position absolute on top of an image, without zoom feature at all, and it was not performant enough when scrolling on low-end computers. This is the reason I'm using canvas now. The problem for me is not really the time it takes to render, but how much what is drawn is consuming resources on old computers (ie keep scroll smooth)

Comment: Also, if you check this version, you can see my canvas has a fixed size and I use a scale transform on it: https://build-ybbdwoumva.now.sh/